# Where is this statement cited by Satadushani found in scripture?

Tags: identification-request, smriti

Vedanta Desikan cites a statement the following *Shatadushani* http://gdurl.com/S8rkW

> For statements such as the following are found in smrtis:
>
> There is no expiation for drinking the milk of a brown cow, for having sexual relations with a Brahmin's wife, and for imparting the Veda to a  Sildra.

(one assumes the Brahmin himself is excluded)

Where is this statement found in scripture?

Comment: Do you know the Sanskrit version?

Comment: Type the link like this and it should work: http://gdurl.com/S8rkW

Comment: Type http:// in front.

Comment: I'll look; but the Sri-Vaishnavites on this forum should know how to get hold of the Sanskrit version @Lazy Lubber

Comment: @LazyLubber Here is the verse in Sanskrit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Whf.jpg

Answer (score 3):

This verse is found in [Parasara Smriti, Chapter 1](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=texte&PhraseID=294813).

> kapilākṣīrapānena brāhmaṇīgamanena ca / (67.1)
>   vedākṣaravicāreṇa śūdraś cāṇḍālatāṃ vrajet // (67.2)

[Translation](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt).

> 67. By drinking the milk of a tawny cow, by cohabiting 
>       with a woman of the Brahman caste, by discussing the 
>       sense of the words of the Veda, a Shoodra becomes a Chandala (Lowest sect)

Comment: This seems different from what Keshav Srinivasan linked to "Here is the verse in Sanskrit": i.stack.imgur.com/r2Whf.jpg

Comment: @SK yes slightly different with that verse.